# How to create Azure DevOps Product Backlog Item using Apache NiFi

Tags: azure, azure-devops, apache-nifi, azure-devops-rest-api

I am developing a component using Apache `NiFi` which should have functionality to create `Azure DevOps` work item in case of any failures. In NiFi side I will be using `NiFi InvokeHTTP` processor which supports HTTP request methods.

I am trying to find out `Azure DevOps` rest API and sample HTTP request that can be used to create a task/work item using a rest call method. I am going through `Azure DevOps` documentations but not getting any sample rest call service that can be used to create task/bug/work item and looking for assistance to build the rest URL to create task/Product Work Items in `VSTS`.

Comment: Do you want a sample to create a work item with rest api?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT. Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) which describe how to create work item with rest api in Azure Devops.

The format of url is:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=5.1-preview.3
```

**Note**: **DO NOT** lost `$` before `{type}`, such as if you want to add task, please refer this sample: `/_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=5.1-preview.3`

For request body:

```
[
     {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "workitem created"
      }
]
```

Comment: This is because you did not use token to execute this api. You can generate PAToken under UserProfile>security.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it is working now. Is there any option to assign the PBI/task to specific team/team member using this API?

Comment: No, it can't. You need to use another api which update work item can achieve this.